# Generate HTML files based on user input

Tags: php, jquery, python, html, function

I am trying to build a website where users enter a word and it generates a page of information accordingly using a function I wrote in python (the function will generate an html file containing the relevant information). As there is an infinite number of words a person can enter, the website needs to automatically run the function (and in doing so write the new html file) in response to user input. From what I can tell, there might be a way to do this using jQuery or PHP, but I was wondering if someone could help me out and let me know if there's a code that would let me easily do this.

Comment: Why dont you just have them enter the `words` in  a `form` and submit it like normal ppl do?

Comment: You need to include HTML and Jquery/javascript in your question along with some input and the desired output so we can understand what you are talking about

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix That doesn't really answer the question in a useful way, and IMO is kind of an unsavory way of brushing off a new user. Codergirl789, your question may be a bit broad for Stack Overflow, as there are a whole ton of different ways you could go about accomplishing that. I would look into Python web frameworks and start learning one!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - thats unsavory?  I was just stating the obvious, I've seen much, much, much worse posted on here.  The `normal` way that the clientside interacts with the `serverside` is via either `get` or `post`, most commonly using a form.   But the more advanced way is `Ajax`.  In either case we probably will need a html page for an interface, just to start.  Some form of UI so the clients will have a way of submitting their data.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form action="getinput.php" method="POST"><input type="text" name="input" /></form>
```

getinput.php

```
<?php $input = $_POST['input']; ?>

//html part of php page
<p><?php echo $input; ?></p>
```

No jQuery needed

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to get this done.  I'm not sure how familiar you are with jQuery, but you could either use the .on function to add an event listener to the input field where users will type their query, or there are individual functions that you can use as shortcuts to .on event listeners.

An example (and this may not work for exactly what you're trying to accomplish, since I'm not 100% certain how things are set up in your code) would be something like:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#myInputField').on('keyup', function(){
              // Your code goes here
          })

     })
</script>
```

You may also be able to do the same thing with the change listener, keydown or others (I don't know them all by memory).  Look here: https://api.jquery.com/on/